# GLX window creation works when called from statically compiled code, but crashes from shared lib

Tags: linux, opengl, x11, glx

I'm trying to strip some GLX window/context creation code out of a
statically-compiled binary and into a shared lib. The same code which
works fine in the static version crashes in the shared lib version on
the first call to any `glX`-prefixed function. As a minimal
(non)working example, here's  `miniglx.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

extern "C"{
  void print_glx_version();
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
}

void print_glx_version()
{
  const char displayID[] = ":0.0";

  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(displayID);

  if (!display)
  {
    printf("Failed to open X display\n");
  }

  int glx_major, glx_minor;

  int res = glXQueryVersion(display, &glx_major, &glx_minor);
  {
    printf("glX version %d.%d\n", glx_major, glx_minor);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  print_glx_version();
  exit(0);
}
```

When I compile as an executable

```
g++ -o miniglx miniglx.cpp -lGL -lX11
```

and run `./miniglx`, it prints `glX version 1.4` as expected.

However, when I compile as a shared lib

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libminiglx.so src/miniglx.cpp -lGL -lX11
```

and try to `dlopen` it in another program and call
`print_glx_version`, it crashes. Running in `gdb` shows that the crash
occurs in the call to `glXQueryVersion` and prints the message

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffecdf6700 (LWP 8774)]
0x00007ffff69a6bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

The shared lib compiles and links fine, and `ldd` shows it seems to
link to `libGL.so` and `libX11.so`:

```
bash$ ldd libminiglx.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff774f000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f94c835a000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f94c8025000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f94c7c5e000)
libnvidia-tls.so.340.32 => /usr/lib/nvidia-340/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.32 (0x00007f94c7a5b000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.340.32 => /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.32 (0x00007f94c4e48000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f94c4c35000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f94c4a31000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f94c4812000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f94c88c4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f94c450b000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f94c4307000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f94c4101000)
```

The one possible difference between the two situations (static vs
dynamic) is that in the static lib case I'm not `dlopen`ing the lib on
the main thread (I have no control over this). Is there some problem
with doing glX window/context management stuff on other threads?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with a `NVIDIA Corporation GT200GL
[Quadro FX 5800] (rev a1)` GPU. The behaviour exist with both the mesa
and nvidia graphics drivers. `glxinfo | head` returns

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
```

Comment: Xlib is not thread safe, but as long as you do everything X11-related in one thread you should be OK.

Comment: @n.m.: xlib is thread-safe, if [XInitThreads()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XInitThreads.html) is used properly.

Comment: @derhass Yes you are right, I always forget about this newfangled  X11R6 stuff ;)

Comment: Hmm, I added the XInitThreads() call, but it's still crashing (same problem).  Will have to investigate further.